# how to set id for Upload or Download Task in Firebase Storage

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

how can i set an **ID** for **Firebase Storage** Upload/Download Task?
for instance if the user tried to upload or download the same file twice and he wants to cancel only one **Download/Upload Task**.
i can get the **ActiveDownloadTasks** using `FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().getActiveDownloadTasks();`
but i don't have **unique id** to cancel a Certain Task.

Answer (score 1):

The SDK doesn't offer any sort of API to assign IDs to downloads.  You'll have to manage that yourself.  You could do that with a simple HashMap object that maps file paths of ongoing transfers to some unique ID you generate.

Comment: could you please provide an Example? i am not sure if i understood you well.
what if the file paths are the same in two download tasks?